# Implementing HMAC authentication

Tags: javascript, jmeter, performance-testing

The application I am performance testing, in jMeter, passes two authentication parameters in the HTTP Header request.  The authentication method used is HMAC authentication in JavaScript using jQuery SHA256.

Does anyone have experience / knowledge implementing this in jMeter, or other performance testing tools ?.

Comment: StackOverflow is about finding answers to specific programming problems. There can be no good answer to a broad question like this. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Given you need to send [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) having HMAC-encoded header:

1. Add [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) as a child of the HTTP Request sampler
2. Put the following code into the PreProcessor's "Script" area

   ```
   import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.HmacUtils;

   String key = vars.get("key");
   String value = vars.get("value");
   String headerValue = HmacUtils.hmacSha256Hex(key, value);

   vars.put("headerValue", headerValue);
   ```
3. Add [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) as a child of HTTP Request sampler and after the Beanshell PreProcessor
4. Configure it to send required header name and use `${headerValue}` as value

   - I cannot guarantee that above code will suit for your application, it may expect slightly different implementation, however it should be enough for you to get the idea. See [HmacUtils class JavaDoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/HmacUtils.html) for all the available methods.
   - Check out [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) to get initial knowledge on Beanshell scripting in JMeter, in particular to learn what `vars` shorthand stands for

Comment: The HMACUTILS.class returns a single HMAC SHA256 value. In my situation there are 2 different parameters generated via JavaScript. Can I still use a Beanshell Pre-processor, and have it call the JavaScript to generate the values ?.  If so, it would be greatly appreciated if you could provide an example of a Beanshell script that calls JavaScript & returns the values it creates ?.

Comment: Either do the same for 2nd value or use [javax.script](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html) namespace or use [JSR223 Post Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) - it allows using javascript language.